# Node js repeating a get request until there is a change in response

Tags: node.js

I will start off by saying I am a complete newbie when it comes to node js. I have the code below which currently sends a get request to the URL. It parses a specific value of the response and stores it as the search variable. It then uses the instagram api to change the bio on my instagram account to that search variable. However I would like the get request to continue until it detects a change. Ex. When the program is first run it fires off a get request. The first response value we get we will call 1. However after the first response I want it to continue to do get requests say every 5 seconds. The moment the response value changes from 1 to anything else I want that new value to be sent to the instagram bio. Can anyone help?

```
 const { IgApiClient } = require("instagram-private-api")
 const ig = new IgApiClient()
 const https = require('https')

 const USERNAME = "MYUSERNAME"
 const PASSWORD = "MYPASS"

 ig.state.generateDevice(USERNAME)


 const main = async () => {

let url = "https://11z.co/_w/14011/selection";
https.get(url,(res) => {
let body = "";

res.on("data", (chunk) => {
    body += chunk;
});

res.on("end", async () => {
    try {
    search = await JSON.parse(body).value;
    
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
    };
});

}).on("error", (error) => {
console.error(error.message);
});

await ig.simulate.preLoginFlow()
await ig.account.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)

 // log out of Instagram when done
 process.nextTick(async () => await ig.simulate.postLoginFlow())

// fill in whatever you want your new Instagram bio to be
await ig.account.setBiography(search)
}

 main()
 // code is written in main() so that I can use async/await
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

to be good citizen to the target endpoint:

have a look on `exponential-backoff` package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/exponential-backoff

> A utility that allows retrying a function with an exponential delay between attempts.